# Whats is type* in the expression std::enable_if

Tags: c++, templates, enable-if

Could someone please explain to me what `type*` means ?

I see in the documentation on std::enable_if this example:

```
// #3, enabled via a parameter
template<class T>
void destroy(
      T* t, 
      typename std::enable_if<std::is_trivially_destructible<T>::value>::type* = 0
    ){
    std::cout << "destroying trivially destructible T\n";
 }
```

Why do we use type here and what is `type*` ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a pointer to a type exposed by `std::enable_if` if `std::is_trivially_destructible<T>::value == true` else it doesn't exist. The default type for it to expose is `void`.

Remember, with SFINAE we're only trying to trigger a substitution error, we can do this by trying to use the `typedef type` of `std::enable_if`. If `std::is_trivially_destructible<T>::value` is `false` then `type` won't exist and the function will be skipped for overload resolution.

We could also specify our own type, maybe that makes it clear:

```
std::enable_if<true, int>::type* intPointer;
```

Here, `intPointer` will be of type `int*`.

---

Without the checks of `enable_if` it'd look a bit like:

```
template <typename T>
struct enable_always
{
  typedef T type;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not `type*`; it's `<the member type of the whole enable_if thing>*`.

`enable_if` is all a bit of a hack; by default that `type` member is just `void`, so all we're doing (if `T` is trivially destructible) is declaring an unnamed template argument of type `void*` that defaults to `0` (or `nullptr`), which we can then completely ignore.

The only reason we have it at all is that, if `T` is *not* trivially destructible, there is no such member type `type`, so this particular specialisation of `destroy` won't exist (by the magic of SFINAE).

It's a bit like going around your neighbours on Hallowe'en, but then not accepting any sweets from them, because you never actually wanted any sweets: you just wanted to see whether your neighbours were home. They're going to be like "why did he/she/it do that? how weird" but you have your answer so there was indeed a purpose to it.

Comment: If you don't want the sweets I'll have them.

Comment: @SombreroChicken Sorry, sweet failure is not an error :D